# Merge 2 columns into 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will like to merge 2 columns into 1 column and remove nan.

I have this data:

```
     Name       A       B   
    Pikachu   2007    nan
    Pikachu   nan     2008
    Raichu    2007    nan
    Mew       nan     2018
```

Expected Result:

```
     Name     Year   
    Pikachu   2007   
    Pikachu   2008   
    Raichu    2007   
    Mew       2008
```

Code I tried:

```
df['Year']= df['A','B'].astype(str).apply(''.join,1)
```

But my result is this:

```
 Name     Year   
Pikachu   2007nan   
Pikachu   nan2008   
Raichu    2007nan   
Mew       nan2008
```

Comment: Is possible values are in both columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns and last convert to integers:

```
df['Year']= df.pop('A').fillna(df.pop('B')).astype(int)

#if possible some missing values in Year column
#df['Year']= df.pop('A').fillna(df.pop('B')).astype('Int64')
print (df)
      Name  Year
0  Pikachu  2007
1  Pikachu  2008
2   Raichu  2007
3      Mew  2018
```

Comment: This is a useful technique for the back pocket - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
df['Year']=df['A'].combine_first(df['B'])
df
```

Output will be as follows.

```
     Name    A       B      Year
0   Pikachu 2007.0  NaN     2007.0
1   Pikachu NaN     2008.0  2008.0
2   Raichu  2007.0  NaN     2007.0
3   Mew     NaN     2018.0  2018.0
```

---

---

To get only `Name` and `year` columns in a new data frame try following.

```
df['Year']=df['A'].combine_first(df['B'])
df1=df[['Name','Year']]
df1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df["Year"] = df["A"] + df["B"]
df = df[['Name','Year']]
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) could be usefull

```
df["A"] = np.where(df["A"].isna(), df["B"], df["A"]).astype("int")
df = df.drop("B", axis=1)
print(df)
    Name    Year
0   Pikachu 2007
1   Pikachu 2008
2   Raichu  2007
3   Mew     2018
```