# Merge 2 dataframe columns into one by matching date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

df

```
           Id   timestamp               data    Date
30424   30665   2020-01-04 19:40:23.827 17.5    2020-01-04
31054   31295   2020-01-05 22:26:39.860 17.0    2020-01-05
32150   32391   2020-01-06 23:00:14.607 18.0    2020-01-06
33236   33477   2020-01-07 22:52:56.757 18.0    2020-01-07
34314   34555   2020-01-08 20:45:48.927 18.0    2020-01-08
35592   35833   2020-01-09 20:56:21.320 18.0    2020-01-09
36528   36769   2020-01-10 20:41:36.323 19.5    2020-01-10
37054   37295   2020-01-11 19:35:50.553 18.5    2020-01-11
37652   37893   2020-01-12 19:28:22.823 17.0    2020-01-12
38828   39069   2020-01-13 23:48:12.533 21.5    2020-01-13
40004   40245   2020-01-14 22:50:56.873 18.5    2020-01-14
```

df1

```
    Date        data 
0   2020-01-04  NaN
1   2020-01-07  NaN
2   2020-01-08  19.0
3   2020-01-09  NaN
4   2020-01-11  NaN
5   2020-01-12  NaN
6   2020-01-16  NaN
7   2020-01-17  NaN
8   2020-01-24  18.5
```

I want to replace the `data` in `df` with values in `df1['data']` if the `df1['data']` value is not `NaN`.

Expected outcome:

```
        Id      timestamp               data    Date
30424   30665   2020-01-04 19:40:23.827 17.5    2020-01-04
31054   31295   2020-01-05 22:26:39.860 17.0    2020-01-05
32150   32391   2020-01-06 23:00:14.607 18.0    2020-01-06
33236   33477   2020-01-07 22:52:56.757 18.0    2020-01-07
34314   34555   2020-01-08 20:45:48.927 19.0    2020-01-08  # This row changed
35592   35833   2020-01-09 20:56:21.320 18.0    2020-01-09
36528   36769   2020-01-10 20:41:36.323 19.5    2020-01-10
37054   37295   2020-01-11 19:35:50.553 18.5    2020-01-11
37652   37893   2020-01-12 19:28:22.823 17.0    2020-01-12
38828   39069   2020-01-13 23:48:12.533 21.5    2020-01-13
40004   40245   2020-01-14 22:50:56.873 18.5    2020-01-14
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58537683/11901732)  is similar but is not the exactly same situation as my question.

I tried:

```
pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', on='Date')
```

which returned:

```
       Id   timestamp               data_x  Date       data_y
0   30665   2020-01-04 19:40:23.827 17.5    2020-01-04  NaN
1   31295   2020-01-05 22:26:39.860 17.0    2020-01-05  NaN
2   32391   2020-01-06 23:00:14.607 18.0    2020-01-06  NaN
3   33477   2020-01-07 22:52:56.757 18.0    2020-01-07  NaN
4   34555   2020-01-08 20:45:48.927 18.0    2020-01-08  19.0
5   35833   2020-01-09 20:56:21.320 18.0    2020-01-09  NaN
6   36769   2020-01-10 20:41:36.323 19.5    2020-01-10  NaN
7   37295   2020-01-11 19:35:50.553 18.5    2020-01-11  NaN
```

---

Update:

Tried:

```
df['data'] = df['Date'].map(df1.set_index('Date')['data']).fillna(df['Date'])
```

but it seems like something is wrong with `data` column:

```
          Id    timestamp               data            Date
30424   30665   2020-01-04 19:40:23.827 1.578096e+18    2020-01-04
31054   31295   2020-01-05 22:26:39.860 1.578182e+18    2020-01-05
32150   32391   2020-01-06 23:00:14.607 1.578269e+18    2020-01-06
33236   33477   2020-01-07 22:52:56.757 1.578355e+18    2020-01-07
34314   34555   2020-01-08 20:45:48.927 1.900000e+01    2020-01-08
35592   35833   2020-01-09 20:56:21.320 1.578528e+18    2020-01-09
36528   36769   2020-01-10 20:41:36.323 1.578614e+18    2020-01-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Date` column first, if no match missing values, so replaced data by original by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['data'] = df['Date'].map(df1.set_index('Date')['data']).fillna(df['data'])
print (df)
          Id                timestamp  data        Date
30424  30665  2020-01-04 19:40:23.827  17.5  2020-01-04
31054  31295  2020-01-05 22:26:39.860  17.0  2020-01-05
32150  32391  2020-01-06 23:00:14.607  18.0  2020-01-06
33236  33477  2020-01-07 22:52:56.757  18.0  2020-01-07
34314  34555  2020-01-08 20:45:48.927  19.0  2020-01-08
35592  35833  2020-01-09 20:56:21.320  18.0  2020-01-09
36528  36769  2020-01-10 20:41:36.323  19.5  2020-01-10
37054  37295  2020-01-11 19:35:50.553  18.5  2020-01-11
37652  37893  2020-01-12 19:28:22.823  17.0  2020-01-12
38828  39069  2020-01-13 23:48:12.533  21.5  2020-01-13
40004  40245  2020-01-14 22:50:56.873  18.5  2020-01-14
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['Date'].map(df1.set_index('Date')['data']))
30424     NaN
31054     NaN
32150     NaN
33236     NaN
34314    19.0
35592     NaN
36528     NaN
37054     NaN
37652     NaN
38828     NaN
40004     NaN
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Do you know what happened to `data` column in the updated question?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Sure, there is typo, `.fillna(df['Date'])` need `.fillna(df['data'])`

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Reason is datetimes are converted to native format, unix format (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54312942/2901002)), so repalced missing values by datetimes in this format

Comment: Why is it necessary to always set the date index (`df1.set_index('Date')`)? Does this mean that many functions are index based?

Comment: @nilsinelabore Reason if need matching values betwen 2 DataFrames same way. Here need matching by `Date`s. Function map working get values of index Series like keys of dictionary and used for assign new values. If no set_index then `df1['data']` has index `0,1,2...` and because this values are not in `Date` column get NaNs in column after `(df['Date'].map(df1['data']))`